# Content Type with Add comment, Post New Article, Share Links

Tags: comments

I have created a drupal page, I want to add comment,share link to the post I have tried using view to create it it does not work out.

Comment: you want to add a `"add comment"` link? So when people click on it, it takes them to the comment box?

Comment: @ssweat yes u got it add coment,post,follow links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add **Add comment** link in view, follow below steps.

1. Add another field to your view i.e. **Content: Nid**
2. In field configuration, remove the title.
3. Select "rewrite the output of this field" and enter "Add comment" in the text area.
4. Now select "output this field as a link" and enter `comment/reply/[nid]#comment-form` in the Link Path field.

To add **Share link**,

1. Install [ShareThis](https://www.drupal.org/project/sharethis) module.
2. Now add share field into your view.

Comment: I want to add New Post link to field not in view

Comment: Means you want to add New Post link field into content type, right? what would be the link URL?